# Evaluating product of integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral:

$$\frac1T \int_0^T dt$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt'$$
$$\int \frac{dw'}{2\pi} e^{-iw'(t-t')} C(w') \left(k \frac{e^{iwt'}e^{-iwt}}{2}\right) \left(-k w \sin(wt)\right)$$

Excuse my bad writing abilities above: This is supposed to be all these three integrals multiplied -- the product of these three integrals.

I am trying to show that the product of these three integrals can be expressed as:

$$\frac{-w k^2}{2} \Im C(w)$$

I have tried to reshuffle terms and I'm pretty sure that I need to use:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt' e^{i(w+-w')t'} = 2\pi \delta(w+-w')$$

However, I have not come close to getting what I need.

w should be expressed as 2*pi/T.

Can anybody, in terms of evaluating the integrals, get closer to what I need to find? :)

Comment: What is meant by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ \mathsf dt'$?

Comment: This doesn't look like a "product of integrals", this looks like a triple integral to me. But it would be good if you provided the original expression as it's supposed to look like (a picture would do), then someone would be able to fix your formatting